# Multiple for loops depending on conditions

Tags: c, for-loop

I wrote the below code, it's working fine.
But somehow i as a newbie don't feel comfortable and think it's possible to write it shorter.

The code basically detects xxx in ipAddress[0-4] and then prints the block ips.

My question is if it's possible to write this shorter and more efficient, in other words can i make the depth of my for loop depend on the value of ipaddress[0]-[4]

Thanks.

```
   short ipAddress[4];

   extractIpAddress(argv[1],&ipAddress[0]);



printf("\nIp Address: %03d. %03d. %03d. %03d\n",ipAddress[0],ipAddress[1],ipAddress[2],ipAddress[3]);

if(ipAddress[0] == 255) {
 for ( ipAddress[0]=0; ipAddress[0] <= 255; ++ipAddress[0] )
    for ( ipAddress[1]=0; ipAddress[1] <= 255; ++ipAddress[1] )
        for (ipAddress[2]=0; ipAddress[2] <= 255; ++ipAddress[2] )
            for (ipAddress[3]=0; ipAddress[3] <= 255; ++ipAddress[3] )
                printf( "%d.%d.%d.%d\n", ipAddress[0], ipAddress[1], ipAddress[2], ipAddress[3]);
}
else if(ipAddress[1] ==255) {
    for ( ipAddress[1]=0; ipAddress[1] <= 255; ++ipAddress[1] )
        for (ipAddress[2]=0; ipAddress[2] <= 255; ++ipAddress[2] )
            for (ipAddress[3]=0; ipAddress[3] <= 255; ++ipAddress[3] )
                printf( "%d.%d.%d.%d\n", ipAddress[0], ipAddress[1], ipAddress[2], ipAddress[3]);
}
else if(ipAddress[2] == 255) {
        for (ipAddress[2]=0; ipAddress[2] <= 255; ++ipAddress[2] )
            for (ipAddress[3]=0; ipAddress[3] <= 255; ++ipAddress[3] )
                printf( "%d.%d.%d.%d\n", ipAddress[0], ipAddress[1], ipAddress[2], ipAddress[3]);
}
else if(ipAddress[3] == 255) {
            for (ipAddress[3]=0; ipAddress[3] <= 255; ++ipAddress[3] )
                printf( "%d.%d.%d.%d\n", ipAddress[0], ipAddress[1], ipAddress[2], ipAddress[3]);
}
```

--Update--

Thanks and sorry for not formulating my question clear.

I'm trying to generate a list of ip addresses, based if the (argv[1] input ipaddress) contains anywhere 255 in it the program will print that complete ip block range, all possible ip addresses.

It's working fine but i just wanted to know and understand if it's possible to write this shorter and more efficiently.

Comment: The wrong format specifier throughout notwithstanding, it was your intent for the first condition to print 4.2 *billion* IP addresses, the second 16.7 million, the third 64K, and the fourth 255 ? Rly ? Secondly, [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) seems more appropriate for this.

Comment: Your `ipAddress` is not initialized. No one knows which `if` will happen (most likely none of them). `The code basically detects xxx in ipAddress[0-4] and then prints the block ips.` - can you please clarify?

Comment: Hey, this question is a little ambiguous in nature, it is unclear exactly what you are asking. Ideally, one wouldn't have to read your code to understand your problem. If you could describe what you are trying to do more precisely, I would be happy to help.

Comment: @dyukha I think he is using the assumption that they are all initialized to 0 as that is the behavior most runtime systems use.

Comment: Sorry guys, i updated my question. I'm trying to loop through all possible ip addresses depending on my argv[1] input (if the ip contains 255). If it contains 255 in any of the ip 4 subblocks 111.222.333.444 it will include that whole block range of ips and print it.

Comment: For example ./displayallips 198.1.255.255 would print all ips from 192.1.0.0 until 198.1.255.255.

Comment: I sounds strange. So for `1.255.1.1` you want to print everything between `1.0.0.0` and `1.255.255.255`?

Comment: In any case, I would write a recursive function, similar to this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-program-to-generate-power-set/. You run recursion from the first index, whose value is `255`.

Comment: @dyukha yes that is my purpose, thanks will have a look.

Comment: Be careful with recursive functions and multiple levels of recursion. Your worst case is `256^4` (that is 4294967296 recursive calls -- each requiring the setup of its own function stack)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, there are 5 levels of recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of recursion is a standard approach when you have to run the same `for` loop on multiple layers.

```
void printAll(short ipAddress[], int index) {
    if (index == 4) {
        printf("%d.%d.%d.%d\n", ipAddress[0], ipAddress[1], ipAddress[2], ipAddress[3]);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        ipAddress[index] = i;
        printAll(ipAddress, index + 1);
    }

}

int main() {
    short ipAddress[4];
    ... // initialize
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (ipAddress[i] == 255) {
            printAll(ipAddress, i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```